# Wordpress display google maps for places through admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making a website for a freelance educator, who makes his lectures on 3-4 different places. I would want to have a google map attached on bottom of the posts where these lectures are occurring.
Is it possible to have a selection of 3-4 radio buttons with these places in the Admin Post-editor, which would insert the google maps iframe through the theme?

Thanks for the help.

BR-:g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably an easier way, but one way of doing this would be:

1. create a custom post type (CPT) called Location
2. install [WP Geo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-geo/) (or similar) and enable it for your new CPT, so each one can be associated with a specific location, and
3. Use the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin to associate the posts (lecture details) with a Location

You may have to write a little code to determine the linked Location for a post, and call the WP Geo functionality to render the map, but it should be fairly straightforward if you have some coding experience.

**EDIT**

Ok, since you're keen on custom fields, try this.  Install the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin, which'll give you radio buttons for the custom fields (I don't think it's possible by default).  Set up a new Field Group called "Course Details", with a single field called "Location".  Associate it with a the appropriate entry type (page or post):
[image: Field definition]

The field will appear in the entry editor like this:
[image: Page Edit]

To get the map to appear in the code, add something like this to the template:

```
    <?php 
        switch (get_field('location')) {
            case "melbourne":
                ?><iframe width="560" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?gl=uk&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=-37.81609,144.967175&amp;spn=0.011866,0.024033&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?gl=uk&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=-37.81609,144.967175&amp;spn=0.011866,0.024033&amp;z=15&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small><?php
                break;
            case "london":
                ?><iframe width="560" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?gl=uk&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=51.508101,-0.128059&amp;spn=0.018697,0.048065&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?gl=uk&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=51.508101,-0.128059&amp;spn=0.018697,0.048065&amp;z=15&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small><?php
                break;
            case "geneva":
                ?><iframe width="560" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?gl=uk&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=46.198369,6.142302&amp;spn=0.020793,0.048065&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?gl=uk&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=46.198369,6.142302&amp;spn=0.020793,0.048065&amp;z=14&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small><?php
                break;
        } ?>
```

The code's just a quick and ugly example, but it should give you an idea of how to use the field.  The URLs come straight from Google Maps - I just clicked the link icon, followed by "Customise and preview embedded map" to get the size I was after.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply... This solution seems a bit hard for me, unfortunately I don't know using custom post types. It is a completely new type of posts, that should be made for this map-insertion function? 
Can it be solved by some Custom fields thing (unfortunately I'm not good in that either, but I've read about it that it can be used in templates somehow, and have a checkbox, that calls different parts of the code)
BR-:g

Comment: Yes, it's a new type of post (instead of "page" or "post", you can create one customized to your content) - see [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types).  You'd need to insert some code into your theme's functions.php to create it.  I guess you could do it with a custom field, especially if the locations were never (or rarely) going to change, but that'd need some code as well.  Can't think of the best way to do that off the top of my head - will give it some thought.

Comment: Yes, the locations don't change (they are standard 4 now), and I would not like to confuse my client (who writes or modifies the posts) with some new type of thing to learn. Thanks for the CPT tipp, it is a new thing for me that I will try to implement in my future jobs. 
Sorry that I'm so sticky with the custom field thing...

Comment: Ok; have added another approach, based on your feedback.

Comment: Sorry again for the late reply, been overloaded with some other stuff...
Thank you for the guidance how to make it with the ACF radio buttons it is exactly how I wanted, and it is a great help in maintaining the site. And also, I can make this kind of easy place choosing for some other sites I'm managing.
A Big Thumbs Up!!!
Best Regards, Gas